# UI elements missing on Modern Apps after upgrading to Windows 10 anniversary edition

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui

After upgrading from Windows 10 to the Anniversary edition, UI elements on Modern Apps aren't showing. For example, take this screenshot from Microsoft Edge:

[image: missing ui elements.]

I've tried `dism` and `sfc` without success. What could be wrong?

Comment: update your gpu driver

Comment: @magicandre1981 Tried without success, I already have the latest version. Though this post on intel forums (https://communities.intel.com/thread/78288?start=45&tstart=0) talk about *downgrading* the driver to make the glitches disappear. I will try that. Though that does not explain why the problem only affected me after the anniversary update, as the video driver wasn't changed with it.

Comment: the Z2xxx chips are not supported in Win10 like my HD4000, so you may see glitches

Comment: @magicandre1981 You were spot on, mine is a Z2760 SoC. Just found a workaround for Edge. Leaving it open and some combination of hibernating/resuming and suspending/resuming makes it render correctly. So I just leave Edge open all the time and after a day of normal usage, the icons end up coming back. For Start Menu / notification glitches, a reboot fixes it. Shame on Intel, this tablet is barely 3 years old and they already not supporting it anymore.

Comment: Just to add for future viewers, I did not downgrade the driver for the workaround to work.